# Command import not found on terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I don't understand why I get this error. I've already looked at other forums and tried

`-bash: import: command not found`

`!/usr/bin/env python3`

And using that doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you mean `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Answer (score 1):

Wow I messed up. In the Mac OSX terminal I didn't type in Python first. That's the solution

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to run a Python program with Bash.  How are you running it?

It appears to have a valid shebang, so either:

1. You're explicitly running "bash".  Don't -- just run the program directly.
2. Your `/usr/bin/env python3` is misconfigured, and is starting Bash instead of Python.  What happens when you run that?

Answer (score -1):

'Import' indicates this line of code should be added to your app entry file, most likely with the other 'import' statements in your index.js or index.jsx, not run in the terminal.